# Update entity from form post

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to update an entity as follows-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditRa(RetailersAssistant ra)
{
    var existingRa = Db.RetailersAssistants.Find(ra.RaId);
    existingRa = ra;
    Db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("RaList", "Admin");
}
```

But it's not updating the database. No exception also. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update each property of `existingRa`  entity. Now, you just assigning new object

Answer (score 1):

You should set the mode of entity as "modified". Please find the solution below:

```
[HttpPost]         

public ActionResult EditRa(RetailersAssistant ra)

{    
var existingRa = Db.RetailersAssistants.Find(ra.RaId);

existingRa  = ra; // If it doesn't work then you can copy each property of ra to existingRa one by one.

Db.Entry(existingRa).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified; 

Db.SaveChanges();

return RedirectToAction("RaList", "Admin");

}
```

Comment: It gives exception.